# Keeping config files sync between linux machines

Tags: linux, synchronization, config

I have several linux clients and servers (virtual and physical) in my home network. I'd like to keep several config files synchron between the machines without copying it manually. Are there (small) solutions which can do it for me? Of course I can write my own scripting solution with rsync, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: You can use [lsyncd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lsyncd). Basically is a daemon which will be listening for changes in specified directory and keep them synchronized.

Comment: @vsergi Thank you. :)